# Rails 'link_to' not working in some mail clients for account confirmation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When confirming account creation, I'm having an issue with the clickable link not displaying in some mail clients, namely gmail.

It worked fine in browser-generated emails in local development, but is now having issues in staging development. The code is as follows:

> Confirm address <%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token) %>

In outlook, it displays both static text "Confirm address" and a clickable "confirm my account" link but in gmail it only displays the text, no ruby code.

Since this is embedded-ruby in html, I'd just put a `href` in but I don't know how to translate the ruby code into html when the ruby code calls on `@token` to create a unique account confirmation URL. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

let's try this:

```
<a href="<%= confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token) %>">Confirm address</a>
```